# Native UI Components that has jni library

Tags: react-native

I found an amazing library to display panoramic images and it has incredible features but it is written in native Java code. So I tried to make it as a UI component in react native by building the bridge between them. After a lot of time of learning and trying, I'm stuck on this:

The panoramaGL library uses JNI library so when I test it on its own it works just fine, BUT it doesn't work on react native because of the JNI library.

Please do me a favor and give me just the tip of the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was ... i've changed the package name while building the bridge between react native and the panoramaGL library so the solution is to change the package name to the old package name of panoramaGL and it works like a charm :)